# Inserting Data Mysql with One Value from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question,
 how to insert data into  database table (mysql) which all data retrieve from php post form and 1 from another table like this?

**PHP Get:**

```
$nama           = $_POST['nama'];
$alamat         = $_POST['alamat'];
$jenis_kelamin  = $_POST['jenis_kelamin'];
$shift          = $_POST['shift'];
```

**Insert Query:**

```
    INSERT INTO test (`id`, `nama`, `alamat`, `jenis_kelamin`, `shift`) VALUES 
('$nama','$alamat','$jenis_kelamin', select id from shift where shift_name = '$shift')"
```

**Here is the output when I try to run these code:**

> Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
>   to use near 'select id from shift where shift_name = 'pagi')' at line
>   1

Comment: I have added the answer. Kindly Check and share your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using insert into select from

```
INSERT INTO test ( `nama`, `alamat`, `jenis_kelamin`, `shift`) 
   select '$nama','$alamat','$jenis_kelamin','$shift' from shift where shift_name = '$shift'
```

Comment: Hey can i ask more question? With your suggest, when I add data, there is show "#1062 - duplicate entry '2' for key 'primary'". I've already set column Id as Primary Key & Auto_Increment. How it's come?

Comment: what is your primary key - is it id column? @ChristianMahardhika

Comment: yep it is id column as primary and auto increment

Comment: @ChristianMahardhika, then please remove id column from insert and select statement, I've mdofied the answer, you can check

Comment: It works... thank you for the solving. I am very appreciated.

Comment: @ChristianMahardhika, glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

The subquery in the values part of the insert statement should be wrapped in paranthesis.

```
Insert into table_name values(col1, col2) values (val1, (select val2 from...));
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Note:** You have to enclose the parenthesis to the select statement that you are using.

Basically when you are concatenating the PHP values to the mysql statements you have to use `''` for inserting the string values into the DB.

```
<?php
$nama           = $_POST['nama'];
$alamat         = $_POST['alamat'];
$jenis_kelamin  = $_POST['jenis_kelamin'];
$shift          = $_POST['shift'];

$query = "INSERT INTO test (`id`, `nama`, `alamat`, `jenis_kelamin`, `shift`) VALUES ('".$nama."','".$alamat."','".$jenis_kelamin."', (SELECT id from shift where shift_name = '".$shift."'))";
?>
```