# Inserting data into Table From Multiple table

Tags: php, mysql, web

I Have a Question in mysql database.

I want to insert some data into a table selected from multiple tables.

This is my query

```
INSERT INTO dapot_dummy ('site_id','rnc_id','wbts_id','ip3g','vlan','status_vlan') 
VALUES (
(SELECT id FROM site WHERE id_site = 'TIM001')
,(SELECT id from rnc where rnc_name = 'RNC Timika-1')
,'117','10.250.46.85','3339',
(SELECT id from status_vlan where status_vlan = 'Metro E'))
```

which I refer in my previous question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52828305/inserting-data-mysql-with-one-value-from-another-table)

Here is the output

> 4 errors were found during analysis.
>
> A comma or a closing bracket was expected (near "SELECT" at position
>   100) Unexpected token. (near "id" at position 107) This type of clause
>   was previously parsed. (near "from" at position 163) Unrecognized
>   statement type. (near "from" at position 163) Query SQL: Dokumentasi
>
> INSERT INTO dapot_dummy
>   ('site_id','rnc_id','wbts_id','ip3g','vlan','status_vlan') VALUES (
>   (SELECT id FROM site WHERE id_site = 'TIM001') ,(SELECT id from rnc
>   where rnc_name = 'RNC Timika-1') ,'117','10.250.46.85','3339', (SELECT
>   id from status_vlan where status_vlan = 'Metro E'))
>
> MySQL menyatakan: Dokumentasi
>
> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near ''site_id','rnc_id','wbts_id','ip3g','vlan','status_vlan') 
>   VALUES (
>       (SELEC' at line 1

How to fix it? Please help

Comment: Really unsure of the point of `'TIM001' from site where id_site = 'TIM001'` - even if it's meant as a subquery - you are selecting the literal `TIM001`.

Comment: I' m sorry I have updated my query

Answer (score 0):

Even the sub query must have valid syntax:

```
INSERT INTO dapot_dummy ('site_id','rnc_id','wbts_id','ip3g','vlan','status_vlan') 
VALUES (
    (SELECT 'TIM001' FROM site WHERE id_site = 'TIM001')
    ,(SELECT 'RNC Timika-1' from rnc where rnc_name = 'RNC Timika-1')
    ,'117','10.250.46.85','3339',
    (SELECT 'Metro E' from status_vlan where status_vlan = 'Metro E'))
```

Hope I hit the tables correctly...

Basically test each sub query on your database to make sure it is valid and you can obtain the data you are expecting, then compose the wide full query..

Comment: Also, subqueries have to have parentheses around them.

Comment: I have try your query but it didnt work.

INSERT INTO dapot_dummy ('site_id','rnc_id','wbts_id','ip3g','vlan','status_vlan') 
VALUES (
    (SELECT id FROM site WHERE id_site = 'TIM001')
    ,(SELECT id from rnc where rnc_name = 'RNC Timika-1')
    ,'117','10.250.46.85','3339',
    (SELECT id from status_vlan where status_vlan = 'Metro E'))

Comment: 4 errors were found during analysis.

A comma or a closing bracket was expected (near "SELECT" at position 100)
Unexpected token. (near "id" at position 107)
This type of clause was previously parsed. (near "from" at position 163)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "from" at position 163)

Comment: Ok, provide structure of all impacted tables: dapot_dummy , site, rnc, status_vlan, and or any I missed since I do not have crystal ball ;)

Comment: @ChristianMahardhika I have updated my answer as well. Two things: 1) provide us the structure of all involved tables, 2) do own troubleshooting by executing each subquery separately to check it works and if you receive the dataset as expected

Answer (score 0):

You should to use '`' backtiks for mark column names instead quotes:

```
INSERT INTO dapot_dummy (`site_id`,`rnc_id`,`wbts_id`,`ip3g`,`vlan`,`status_vlan`) 
VALUES (
    (SELECT id FROM site WHERE id_site = 'TIM001')
    ,(SELECT id FROM rnc WHERE rnc_name = 'RNC Timika-1')
    ,'117','10.250.46.85','3339',
    (SELECT id FROM status_vlan WHERE status_vlan = 'Metro E'))
```

Also I advice to add `LIMIT 1` to sub-queries